# Calling Async method from Custom Controller Factory in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using a custom controller factory (by extending `DefaultControllerFactory`) and calling a Custom `ActionInvoker` (overriding `InvokeAction` method). Now i need to call an Async method from this custom `ActionInvoker` method.

Problem is there is no corresponding Async `InvokeAction` method present which I can override and use to call my Async method from it. Please let me know if you have any suggestion or inputs for calling Async method from `InvokeAction` method.

Below is the code sample to make things bit clear.

```
public class CustomControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    // Assign custom Action Invoker
    controller.ActionInvoker = new CustomActionInvoker();     
}

public class CustomActionInvoker: ControllerActionInvoker
{
    public override bool InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
        string actionName)
    {
        // can not use await here since InvokeAction method can not be marked Async
        var result =  await GetView()
        base.InvokeActionResult(controllerContext, view);
        Return true;
    }
}
```

UPDATE :

Can i call my Async GetView method from Synchronous method (InvokeAction). My GetView() Async method is basically downloading file from external source (Network operation). I guess i can wrap GetView() call in Task.Run so that my main Asp thread will be available to serve some other web request. Will Task.Run get the thread from Asp thread pool only? If yes then i guess there is no real advantage since anyway going to consume Asp thread pool which i do not want.

Comment: Why can't to be marked as Async?  Async isn't part of a methods signature.

Comment: @ErikPhilips the method returns bool, marking it async would mean it would need to return `Task<bool>`

Comment: Is this what you're looking for [AsyncControllerActionInvoker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.async.asynccontrolleractioninvoker?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)

Comment: @JSteward agreed, but that doesn't make my statement invalid.

Comment: I am overiding InvokeAction method and it can not be marked Async since ControllerActionInvoker class does not support any AsyncInvokeAction method.

Comment: @ErikPhilips The statement that the return value of the method cannot be what it would need to be for it to compile does indeed make your statement invalid.

Comment: @JSteward, I already looked into AsyncControllerActionInvoker  but i was not sure how i can use BeginInvokeAction in my code. I guess its purpose is different.

Comment: @ErikPhilips, I can not change method signature InvokeAction since it dose not support  Async Task<bool> kind of signature. Thats what i wanted to know if there is anything i can do here.

Comment: This is why I made a comment.  Async is not part of a method signature, its a compiler hint.  What you should be asking is, how can I change the result type.

Comment: @ErikPhilips if a method is marked as `async` then it has to return `Task`, `Task<T>` or `void`.  So OP would face a compile error by adding `async` no matter what

Comment: @maccettura And changing the method signature won't compile as it's an override, so the options are simply which compiler error you get, not whether or not it compiles.

Comment: @Servy good point

Comment: Totally different scenario so everyone here understand the difference.  A method that returns `Task<int>` can either have or not have `async`, but you cannot create one with both, because `async` [is not part of a method signature](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SQJTyu).  Everything else said is inferred from that statement and really has nothing to do with an answer, thus why I haven't made an answer.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use Async behavior in this way

```
    protected override IAsyncResult BeginInvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor,
        IDictionary<string, object> parameters, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {

        // Initiate the asychronous call.
        var asyncResult = yourMethod.BeginInvoke(<your params>);

        // Wait for the WaitHandle to become signaled.
        asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

        // Perform additional processing here.
        // Call EndInvoke to retrieve the results.
        var returnObject = yourMethod.EndInvoke(asyncResult);

        asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.Close();


        return base.BeginInvokeActionMethod(controllerContext, actionDescriptor, parameters, callback, state);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Simonare, I will try your suggestion.